# \chapter*{Introduction} with custom header without "Chapter 0"

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I would like to have the first chapter* page ''Introduction'' with the `\pagestyle{plain}` format, and the next pages of this same chapter with a header like this (and if it is possible to choose between upper and lower case): [image]

The problem arises when I try to do it, I get the chapter page with this heading instead of the plain page style:

[image]

---

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
            \chaptername}\ \thechapter.%
        \ #1}{}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    
    \phantomsection
    \section*{Resum}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Resum}
    \lipsum[1]
    \clearpage
    
    \tableofcontents
    \pagestyle{headings}
    \clearpage
    
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures
    \pagestyle{headings} %for the next pages of the list of figures
    
    \clearpage
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\chaptername}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \chapter*{Introducció}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introdució}
    \chaptermark{Introducció}
    \thispagestyle{headings}
    \lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
            \chaptername}\ \thechapter.%
        \ #1}{}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    
    \phantomsection
    \section*{Resum}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Resum}
    \lipsum[1]
    \clearpage
    
    \tableofcontents
    \pagestyle{headings}
    \clearpage
    
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures
    \pagestyle{headings} %for the next pages of the list of figures
    
    \clearpage
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\slshape{INTRODUCCIÓ}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \chapter*{Introducció}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introdució}
    \chaptermark{Introducció}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    
\end{document}
```